# Multiple text inputs with same name - add to database

Tags: php, arrays, post, input, foreach

I have a form with several fields, all of which can be multiplied

```
<input type="text" name="child_name[]" />
<input type="text" name="child_age[]" />
<input type="text" name="child_gender[]" />    
<input type="text" name="child_school[]" />
```

I want to add multiple rows to a table in the database using a foreach, but every time I try I get an error saying

```
"Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'"
```

When i print out the data it shows all of the fields as arrays, so I must be doing something wrong with the foreach statement, but I have no idea what

```
Array ( [child_name] => Array ( [0] => child one [1] => child two) [child_age] => Array ( [0] => 14 [1] => 13 ) [child_gender] => Array ( [0] => male [1] => female ) [child_school] => Array ( [0] => burnside [1] => summer heights high ) )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!#

UPDATED

Here is the code for my foreach

```
foreach ($_POST['child_name'] as $child_name)
    {
        $insert_children_data = array(
            'child_name' => $_POST['child_name'],
            'child_age' => $_POST['child_age'],
            'child_gender' => $_POST['child_gender'],
            'child_school' => $_POST['child_school']
        );
        $insert = $this->db->insert('portrait_children', $insert_children_data);
        return $insert;
    }
```

Comment: Show your query please.

Comment: what code you have in `foreach`..?

Comment: you must use two `foreach`, one for `$_POST` fields, second for fields in `key`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (assuming your form got same number of elements for each of the child_name, child_age etc):

```
for ($ix=0; $ix<count($_POST['child_name']); $ix++)
{
    $insert_children_data = array(
        'child_name' => $_POST['child_name'][$ix],
        'child_age' => $_POST['child_age'][$ix],
        'child_gender' => $_POST['child_gender'][$ix],
        'child_school' => $_POST['child_school'][$ix]
    );

    $insert = $this->db->insert('portrait_children', $insert_children_data);
    //return $insert; //you cant return here. must let the loop complete.
}
```

Comment: I am receiving a syntax error "syntax error, unexpected ';'" at $ix=0; any ideas?

Comment: did you try the updated version. See the updated version above. I left a small typo and fixed it now.

Comment: YES it works! Thank you so very very much :) when I get a high enough reputation I will vote you up :)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an array to a key, which is not feasible, try looping all the elements

```
foreach ($_POST as $key)<br>
{<br>
    foreach($key as $v=>$v1)<br>
    {<br>
        $s[$v] = $v1;<br>
    }<br>

}<br>
print_r($s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make one array. array contain all the data of particular child like

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
  [name] => child1 
  [age] => 5 
  [gender] => male
  [school] => 1school )
[1] => Array (
  [name] => child2 
  [age] => 10 
  [gender] => male
  [school] => school2 )
```

Please try below Code

```
$i =0;  

foreach($_REQUEST['child_name'] as $child)

{

$child1[$i]['name'] = $child;

$i++;

}

$i =0;  

foreach($_REQUEST['child_age'] as $child)

{

$child1[$i]['age'] = $child;

$i++;

}

$i =0;  

foreach($_REQUEST['child_gender'] as $child)

{

$child1[$i]['gender'] = $child;

$i++;

}

$i =0;  

foreach($_REQUEST['child_school'] as $child)

{

$child1[$i]['school'] = $child;

$i++;

} 
$insert = $this->db->insert('portrait_children', $child1);
    return $insert;
```