# disable and enable onclick event not working for multiple rows

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, database

I am working on a php project,

well, i  need help like i have 10 records to update data to database see the diag below-

[image]

now like you see No_Info option , says : No_Data and Available.

So when user click for No_data for ID:1 , it disable fields that are attached to corresponding id.
and same available works.

But it only all working for ID: 1  , for no other row its working.....

EDIT:  Update code here.

```
>>>> <?php
//connect to the database server
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or  die(mysql_error()); 
//select the database 
$objDB = mysql_select_db("main_project"); 
//select which data you want to get.
$sql           = "SELECT * FROM website_maindb";
$objQuery      = mysql_query($sql);
// $Ct = mysql_query('select * from company_type');
/* $objResult     = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);   // Not to use when using loop to call full database */
?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>ss</title>
    <script>
function disable()
{
document.getElementById("noi1").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("noi2").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("noi3").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("noi4").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("noi5").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("noi6").disabled=true;

}
function enable()
{
document.getElementById("noi1").disabled=false;
document.getElementById("noi2").disabled=false;
document.getElementById("noi3").disabled=false;
document.getElementById("noi4").disabled=false;
document.getElementById("noi5").disabled=false;
document.getElementById("noi6").disabled=false;
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body>

<form id="form" action="insert.php" method="post">
<table width="700" border="1">  
<tr> 
<th></th>  
<th width="20"> <div align="center">ID </div></th>  
<th width="98"> <div align="center">website </div></th> 
<th width="98"> <div align="center">category </div></th>
<th width="98"> <div align="center">email </div></th>
<th width="98"> <div align="center">contact form </div></th> 
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Primary No. </div></th> 
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Secondary No. </div></th> 
<th width="98"> <div align="center">fax </div></th> 
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Company type </div></th> 
<th width="98"> <div align="center">No_Info </div></th> 
<th width="98"> <div align="center">time </div></th> 
</th>  
</tr>
<?php
$options = '';
$Ctype=mysql_query("select distinct typec from company_type");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Ctype)) {
    $options .="<option>" . $row['typec'] . "</option>";
}
?>

<?php 
$i = 0;  
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))  
{  
$i++;  
?>  
<tr>  
<td><input type="hidden" name="WID" value="<?=$objResult["WID"];?>"></td>  
<td><label><input type="text" name="ID" value="<?=$objResult["WID"];?>" disabled></label></td>  
<td><input type="text" name="website" value="<?=$objResult["website"];?>"></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="cat" size="10"></td> 
<td><input type="text" id="noi1" name="email" size="10"></td> 
<td><input type="text" id="noi2" name="cform" size="10"></td>  
<td><input type="text" id="noi3" name="contactp" size="10"></td>  
<td><input type="text" id="noi4" name="contacts" size="10"></td>  
<td><input type="text" id="noi5" name="fax" size="10"></td>  
<td><select id="Ctype" name="Ctype"> <?="  $options  "?> </select></td>  
<td><button type="button" onclick="disable()" size="20">No_Data</button> </br>
<button type="button" onclick="enable()" size="20">Available</button> 
</td>  
<td><input type="text" id="noi6" name="time" size="10"></td>  
</tr> 
<?php  
}  
?> 
<button type="submit" id="send">Submit</button>
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

can anyone help solving it..

Comment: You might want to add the code in the question because to view it in pastebin you need an account and I doubt if everyone has a pastebin account.

Comment: This is a private paste.

Comment: 1. you usually paste relevant code here on SO because pastebin coudl go down some day and if SO stil  exists you wouldnt be able to reread thsi question. 2. your pastebin is private!

Comment: updated the code here. sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it slightly wrong. You have to build the form fields in array. like this:

`<input type="text" id="noi1_<?php echo $i; ?>" name="email[]" size="10">`

.

and your buttons like this:

`<button type="button" onclick="disable('<?php echo $i; ?>')" size="20">No_Data</button>`

.

then, in your JS:

```
function disable(idx)
{
  document.getElementById("noi1_"+idx).disabled=true;
  .
  .
```

.
.

Then finally when you receive the form in $_POST, you will get $_POST['email'] as an array.

Comment: One more question, like my application page is showing data from database eg. 7 records that are available then when i update all fields like you see the form in image, it should update all fields in database but it is only updating last row in database not all. And in case of multiple selection in dropdown it again doing issues like when we select 1 category in row 1 and 1 category in row 7 then it is showing both category selection with comma spaced in row 7 as stored in db. why so ?

Comment: that actually depends upon your script which is processing the `$_POST` when they are received. Just remember, you have to loop the results when you receive them (as for example, you will get $_POST['email'] as an array) and run insert query on all of them in the loop. Otherwise, it will only save the last one.

Comment: See my reply over here. This is exactly your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898161/multiple-text-inputs-with-same-name-add-to-database/15898444#15898444

Comment: and since i have added array to the email or all options, i am unable to save the O/P. getting error as:  Notice: Array to string conversion in C:/.. 

One more thing, i want to store the label of button (eg: No_Info and Available) to database when sent button is clicked finally.

Comment: If you want to save "disabled", you need to create a hidden input field (say mark_disable) with default value as "0" for each row in the table. Then in the JS disable() function, you will fill its value (like "1" for disable)

Comment: do you have any skype or anything , it seems you can help me you understanding my issue well.

Comment: email me your id at `rh2@yopmail.com` (temporary email to prevent spam :D)

Comment: Sent. check your inbox before it explode.

Comment: got it and delete the email... so youre safe too. :D

Comment: add me, i am waiting at skype.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Please Share the Enable code...**


$(document).ready(function() {

$("#submit").click(function() {
var name = $("#name").val();
var cname = $("#cname").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var contact = $("#contact").val();
var msg = $("#msg").val();
if (name == '' || cname == ''|| email == '' || contact == '' ||  msg == '') {
alert("Insertion Failed Some Fields are Blank....!!");
} else {
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.

$.post("re.php", {
name1: name,
cname1: cname,
email1: email,
contact1: contact,
msg1: msg
}, function(data) {
alert(data);
//$('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields

});

}

});
function NextButton() {        

mySubmitButton = document.getElementById("submit");        

mySubmitButton.click();

myOpenButton = document.getElementById("form1");       

myOpenButton.click();    

 }
$("#submit").click(function(){

    $("#name").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#cname").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#email").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#contact").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#msg").prop("disabled",true);
});


$("#submit1").click(function() {
var name3 = $("#name3").val();
var cname3 = $("#cname3").val();
var email3 = $("#email3").val();
var contact3 = $("#contact3").val();
var msg3 = $("#msg3").val();
if (name3 == '' || cname3 == ''|| email3 == '' || contact3 == '' ||  msg3 == '') {
alert("Insertion Failed Some Fields are Blank....!!");
} else {
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.

$.post("re.php", { 
name4: name3,
cname4: cname3,
email4: email3,
contact4: contact3,
msg4: msg3
}, function(data) {
alert(data);
//$('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields

});
}
});
$("#submit1").click(function(){

    $("#name3").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#cname3").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#email3").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#contact3").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#msg3").prop("disabled",true);
});
}); 

This code for a disable value coding please share the value enable coding
```

Comment: Add some description instead of dumping the code only.